# is it possible to parameterize the class / any declaration

Tags: java

see this..... I am asking this question in order to create Custom Control for Scene Builder.
PARENT PROCEDURE

```
static private javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> fathers = javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

CLASS DECLARATION

```
public class APerson {
}
```

CHILD PROCEDURE which is called by PARENT PROCEDURE

```
@FXML
ComboBox<?> myComboBox<>;
.
.
.
public ComboBox<> createSpecialComboBox(Class myClass, javafx.collections.ObservableList<myClass> myData)  {

    ComboBox<myClass> myComboBox = new ComboBox<myClass>();
    myComboBox.setItems(myData);
}
```

Is this feasible ? I don't want to create different custom classes for APerson, AFather, AChild..... blah blah. Right now I have hard coded  in the Child Procedure.

Is there a better solution.

Thanks, Gold

Comment: "_I don't want to create different custom classes for APerson, AFather, AChild_" Why do you think you have to? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the ANSWER. If I declare the combobox as

```
private ComboBox<T> myCustomCombo;
```

instead of

```
private ComboBox<APerson> myCustomCombo;
```

I am able to send Strings and other Object types to myCustomCombo.